# HTML / jQuery : I want to load banners from another file

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I'm new to jQuery but a friend recommended to use it for this.

I want to load banners dynamiclly from another location into an advertisement box. I have made it cycle though the banners with this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.banner').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
```

That works fine, but the links still have to be within the html file, I want to be able to edit a single file and it will update the banners on all them templates.

Any help?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.banner').load('banner.html').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
```

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/